# Webpack and gulp

Tags: gulp, webpack

I am confused about Webpack and gulp. I know gulp is task runner and webpack is module bundler, but it seems like there are many overlapping features? like compile, minification, temp live server etc. My question is can I replace gulp with webpack in production?

I know gulp has so many features, but I am mostly focusing minification, concatenation, live server, live reload, uglify, sourcemap.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the features that webpack provides then it's better to use webpack along with [webpack dev server](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html). Using both is redundant.

I'm currently using grunt and webpack in some of my projects that originally were grunt to concat, minify, and test. Now I spawn webpack and karma using [grunt-concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent).

Comment: I was previously using Prepros and I find it easy to use. I'd like to know why people prefer gulp over precompile app in a team environment even the tasks are as simple as I listed?

Comment: Mainly from what I've seen is  the fact that the build steps are shareable and configurable. On a bigger team it's easier for everyone to be able to see what the build steps are and be able to change them without having everyone else do something to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the task runner vs. module bundler. The difference is that you tell Gulp *how* to put front-end code together step-by-step, but you tell Webpack *what* you want through a config file. So it's not just about the functionality overlap, but more of a mindset change.

Here is a short article (5 min read) I wrote explaining the differences with simple examples: https://medium.com/@Maokai/compile-the-front-end-from-gulp-to-webpack-c45671ad87fe

Our company moved from Gulp to Webpack in the past year. Although it took some time, we figured out how to move all we did in Gulp to Webpack. So to us, everything we did in Gulp can also be done through Webpack, but not the other way around.